# angular-translate prevent lang-keys flashing after route-change

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

When the angular-router loads a page after changing route, the language-keys are visible for a few milliseconds. Then they get replaced by its language-value.
I'd like to avoid this, but I have no clue how to fix it.

config.js:

```
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage(appConfig.preferredLanguage);
$translateProvider.fallbackLanguage(appConfig.preferredLanguage);
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader(
  {
    prefix: 'assets/dictionary/language/',
    suffix: '.json'
  }
);
$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escapeParameters');
$translateProvider.use(appConfig.preferredLanguage);
```

example-template:

```
<p ng-show="loginForm.username.$error.required">{{"LOGIN.ENTER_USERNAME" | translate}}</p>
```

Versions:

```
Angular: 1.4.4
Angular-Translate: 2.8.0
```

Comment: why dont you put expression inside ng-bind or you can use ng-cloak on p tag.

Comment: that wouldn't solve my problem. i've tried that, too.

Comment: U can try route resolve method to resolve the things you are loading then show the page

Comment: But the language file already has been loaded.